# Use SQL to Query another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm try an alternative to solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156402/initialization-of-data-source-failed-excel-2013) using VBA to get the data.

The following code works fine when "Tbltest" is a range but not working when the name represent a table. How can I make it work with Table not range.

```
Function ConnectToExelPRJReview()

Dim Xlpath As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandlerconnection:

Dim Xlcn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Xlrs As ADODB.Recordset

Xlpath = "\\xxx.xxx.xxxxxx.net\project_review\wip\" & "filetotest.xlsm"
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Xlpath _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set Xlcn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Xlrs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Xlcn.Open strCon


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Tbltest]"

Xlrs.Open strSQL, Xlcn

'display the first data

MsgBox Xlrs.Fields(0).Value

Xlcn.Close

Exit Function
ErrHandlerconnection:
MsgBox Err.Number & "   " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "EXCEL CONNECTION ERROR"

End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: HI, I don't think it's possible, looking at the schema(`connection.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)`) of a workbook, with 3 sheets, and 1 table, gives the following `Sheet1$;Sheet2$;Sheet3$` as possible tables to query from, my table Table1 is not there.

Comment: If the named range works, then you could try using both, a named range that is built off `offset` from an anchor top left of your table, counta right and down for it's dimensions.  Not 100% sure it will work from o/s tho

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will stay with named range.